# How to delete selected values in an sql-database-array

Tags: php, html, mysql

By using an html-form, I want to read out data from an sql-database and show them in an html-table. This works fine! Now, I want to reduce the number of columns in the table AFTER the sql-select-query.

`$field = mysqli_fetch_fields($result)` returns the column-names and `var_dunp($field)` returns the folowing result:

> array(11) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (13) { ["name"]=> string(2) "id" ["orgname"]=> string(2) "id" ["table"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["orgtable"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["def"]=> string(0) "" ["db"]=> string(4) "team" ["catalog"]=> string(3) "def" ["max_length"]=> int(1) ["length"]=> int(11) ["charsetnr"]=> int(63) ["flags"]=> int(49667) ["type"]=> int(3) ["decimals"]=> int(0) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#4 (13) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Vorname" ["orgname"]=> string(7) "Vorname" ["table"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["orgtable"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["def"]=> string(0) "" ["db"]=> string(4) "team" ["catalog"]=> string(3) "def" ["max_length"]=> int(9) ["length"]=> int(60) ["charsetnr"]=> int(33) ["flags"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(253) ["decimals"]=> int(0) } [2]=> object(stdClass)#5 (13) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Name" ["orgname"]=> string(4) "Name" ["table"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["orgtable"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["def"]=> string(0) "" ["db"]=> string(4) "team" ["catalog"]=> string(3) "def" ["max_length"]=> int(14) ["length"]=> int(60) ["charsetnr"]=> int(33) ["flags"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(253) ["decimals"]=> int(0) } [3]=> object(stdClass)#6 (13) { ["name"]=> string(3) "Str" ["orgname"]=> string(3) "Str" ["table"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["orgtable"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["def"]=> string(0) "" ["db"]=> string(4) "team" ["catalog"]=> string(3) "def" ["max_length"]=> int(22) ["length"]=> int(60) ["charsetnr"]=> int(33) ["flags"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(253) ["decimals"]=> int(0) } [4]=> object(stdClass)#7 (13) { ["name"]=> string(3) "PLZ" ["orgname"]=> string(3) "PLZ" ["table"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["orgtable"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["def"]=> string(0) "" ["db"]=> string(4) "team" ["catalog"]=> string(3) "def" ["max_length"]=> int(4) ["length"]=> int(15) ["charsetnr"]=> int(33) ["flags"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(254) ["decimals"]=> int(0) } [5]=> object(stdClass)#8 (13) { ["name"]=> string(3) "Ort" ["orgname"]=> string(3) "Ort" ["table"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["orgtable"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["def"]=> string(0) "" ["db"]=> string(4) "team" ["catalog"]=> string(3) "def" ["max_length"]=> int(10) ["length"]=> int(90) ["charsetnr"]=> int(33) ["flags"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(253) ["decimals"]=> int(0) } [6]=> object(stdClass)#9 (13) { ["name"]=> string(3) "Tel" ["orgname"]=> string(3) "Tel" ["table"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["orgtable"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["def"]=> string(0) "" ["db"]=> string(4) "team" ["catalog"]=> string(3) "def" ["max_length"]=> int(11) ["length"]=> int(75) ["charsetnr"]=> int(33) ["flags"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(253) ["decimals"]=> int(0) } [7]=> object(stdClass)#10 (13) { ["name"]=> string(5) "EMail" ["orgname"]=> string(5) "EMail" ["table"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["orgtable"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["def"]=> string(0) "" ["db"]=> string(4) "team" ["catalog"]=> string(3) "def" ["max_length"]=> int(20) ["length"]=> int(90) ["charsetnr"]=> int(33) ["flags"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(253) ["decimals"]=> int(0) } [8]=> object(stdClass)#11 (13) { ["name"]=> string(3) "WWW" ["orgname"]=> string(3) "WWW" ["table"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["orgtable"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["def"]=> string(0) "" ["db"]=> string(4) "team" ["catalog"]=> string(3) "def" ["max_length"]=> int(17) ["length"]=> int(90) ["charsetnr"]=> int(33) ["flags"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(253) ["decimals"]=> int(0) } [9]=> object(stdClass)#12 (13) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Notizen" ["orgname"]=> string(7) "Notizen" ["table"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["orgtable"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["def"]=> string(0) "" ["db"]=> string(4) "team" ["catalog"]=> string(3) "def" ["max_length"]=> int(13) ["length"]=> int(196605) ["charsetnr"]=> int(33) ["flags"]=> int(16) ["type"]=> int(252) ["decimals"]=> int(0) } [10]=> object(stdClass)#13 (13) { ["name"]=> string(10) "Geburtstag" ["orgname"]=> string(10) "Geburtstag" ["table"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["orgtable"]=> string(8) "adressen" ["def"]=> string(0) "" ["db"]=> string(4) "team" ["catalog"]=> string(3) "def" ["max_length"]=> int(10) ["length"]=> int(30) ["charsetnr"]=> int(33) ["flags"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(253) ["decimals"]=> int(0) } }

Since this is an array, I now want to remove selected elements from this array and tried to do this with:

```
    // Initilize what to delete
        $delete_val = array('PLZ');
    //     Search for the array key and unset
           foreach($delete_val as $key){
              $keyToDelete = array_search($key, $field);
              unset($field[$keyToDelete]);
           }
```

or with

```
      $toremove = "PLZ";
      $field = array_flip($field);
      unset($field[$toremove]);
      $field = array_flip($field);
```

However, both ways did not work. Obviously, the element I want to remove is not found within the array with this methods.

In a second step, I have to modify the while-loop, so that the correct values are shown in the respective columns:

```
      $nr = 1;
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<td>" . $nr . "</td>";
        for ($k=0; $k<$numcols; $k++) {    
        echo "<td>" . $row[$k] . "</td>"; //Prints the data
        }
      echo "</tr>";
      $nr = $nr + 1;
      }     // ende of while-loop
```

I would be grateful if somebody could help me with this Problem!

Comment: You should get into the habit of *accepting* answers, it'll encourage other developers to help your further. Right now, it seems like all of your questions are on free-floating *open* state. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out, unfortunately I didn´t know that until now! I have already marked the question as answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not *normal* array, that's an array of objects, which is what's expected from [`mysqli_fetch_fields()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) function, so your delete logic won't work in *that* fashion. Your code should be like this:

(Suppose `PLZ` is the column you want to delete here)

```
// Initilize what to delete
$delete_val = array('PLZ');
// Search for the array key and unset
foreach($delete_val as $dv){
    foreach($field as $key => $object){
        $array = (array)$object;
        if(in_array($dv, $array, true)){
            unset($field[$key]);
        }
    }   
}
$field = array_values($field);

// display $field array
var_dump($field);
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, I can remove single values from my sql-array! However, the rows of my table do not fit anymore since the values of the removed column are still present. How can I modify the while-loop so that the right values are in the remaining columns? 

echo "<tr>";     
echo "<th>" . 'Nr' . "</th>";
for($x=0;$x<$numcols;$x++){
echo "<th>" . $field[$x]->name . "</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
$nr = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<td>" . $nr . "</td>";
for ($k=0; $k<$numcols; $k++) {
echo "<td>" . $row[$k] . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
$nr = $nr + 1;
}

Comment: @Columbus Is there any specific reason why you're fetching array values as numeric array i.e `$row[$k]`, and not as associative arrays i.e. `$row['column_name']`?

Comment: Since I created the rows with a for-loop, I used a numeric array. However, how can I modify my rows according to my column-names with an associative array? This won´t work without a loop, will it?

Comment: @Columbus Never mind, everything's good. You just need to change this line `echo "<td>" . $row[$k] . "</td>";` to `echo "<td>" . $row[$field[$k]->name] . "</td>";`. Here's the code snippet, [http://pastebin.com/m8Wh2Nsb](http://pastebin.com/m8Wh2Nsb)

Comment: @Columbus Also, I believe that this statement `echo "<tr>";` should be inside the `while` loop, as I pointed out in the pastebin code snippet. Here's a *more* complete code snippet, [http://pastebin.com/1AECFzda](http://pastebin.com/1AECFzda)

Comment: Again, thank you very much, Paul, now the values are in the right columns! :)There is only one little problem: for every value I remove from the SQL-database-array, an empty column without field-name and values is remaining at the end of the table. Is there any possibility not to show these empty columns?

Comment: @Columbus Could you provide a screenshot of that behaviour? Also, how are you calculating this `$numcols`?

Comment: Thanks for your question, how to calculate $numcols! I just found the mistake! Now, it is working perfectly! How can I mark my problem as solved? :)

Comment: @Columbus You've already done that, see the green tick on the left side of the answer. ;-)

Comment: Then I have to thank you again Paul, you saved my day!! :)

Comment: A final question just arose: is there any possibility to rename the columns in the html-table or do I have to use the column-names from the SQL-database?

Comment: @Columbus Yes, you can certainly use custom names for your db column names. Declare an array like this: `$column_array = array('custom_column1' => 'db_column1', 'custom_column2' => 'db_column2', ...);` and use this array in your code i.e if a value matches in the array, use the corresponding key i.e custom column name.

Comment: Paul, could you please give me an example, how I can use this array in my code? Do I have to use "in_array()"?

Comment: @Columbus Okay, I'll give you a short example with respect to the question you asked above. What columns does your table have? Also, if your requirement is quite exhaustive and complex, I'd suggest you to raise a separate question on SO.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! e.g. the db_column_name is "birth_day" and I would like to have "Geburtstag" (= german word for birthday) as column_name in my table.

Comment: @Columbus Here's an example, [http://pastebin.com/UbjTJHnv](http://pastebin.com/UbjTJHnv). You can construct this `$custom_column_arr` array like I explained in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948671/how-to-delete-selected-values-in-an-sql-database-array/39948989?noredirect=1#comment67207507_39948989).

Comment: Thank you again for your help, Paul! It was a great pleasure for me to learn from you! :)